# Show/hide fields depending on select value

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am trying to show and hide a few form fields depending on the value of one of my select fields. I am looking to use arrays to hold what should be shown and what should not be shown for each select value, to save me from a massive switch statement, but cannot figure out how to do it.

I am using PHP and jQuery. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<select id="viewSelector">
   <option value="0">-- Select a View --</option>       
   <option value="view1">view1</option>
   <option value="view2">view2</option>
   <option value="view3">view3</option>
</select>

<div id="view1">
  <!-- content --> 
</div>
<div id="view2a">
  <!-- content --> 
</div>
<div id="view2b">
  <!-- content --> 
</div>
<div id="view3">
  <!-- content --> 
</div>
```

then in the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.viewMap = {
    '0' : $([]),
    'view1' : $('#view1'),
    'view2' : $('#view2a, #view2b'),
    'view3' : $('#view3')
  };

  $('#viewSelector').change(function() {
    // hide all
    $.each($.viewMap, function() { this.hide(); });
    // show current
    $.viewMap[$(this).val()].show();
  });
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the early post, finger slipped on the keyboard.  Looks like I got a downvote for it.

Comment: Should this.hide(); be replaced with $(this).hide();

Comment: I tested this and it works.  Just note, you may need to initially hide the views/show the default.

Comment: @Jose, not from my tests.  this as already the wrapped set object.

Comment: I added a null default option

Comment: That works beautifully.. gotta love Jquerry, and those who produce examples like this

Answer (score 6):

There are a few different ways you could do this. The simplest is to have a few separate fieldsets, each one containing a single group of fields. Then, in jQuery, dependent on the select-menu's value you can show/hide these fieldsets, e.g.

```
<fieldset id="f1">
    <input name="something1" />
    <input name="something2" />
    <input name="something3" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset id="f2">
    <input name="something4" />
    <input name="something5" />
    <input name="something6" />
</fieldset>
<select name="fieldset-choice">
    <option value="f1">Fieldset 1</option>
    <option value="f2">Fieldset 2</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('select[name=fieldset-choice]').change(function(){
        var fieldsetName = $(this).val();
        $('fieldset').hide().filter('#' + fieldsetName).show();
    });

    // We need to hide all fieldsets except the first:
    $('fieldset').hide().filter('#f1').show();
</script>
```

**Note**: For the above technique to be entirely unobtrusive you might want to dynamically build the select-menu with the names of all the different fieldsets.

---

Alternatively you can prefix each fields name with a meaningful prefix, and then hide/show according to that attribute:

```
<input name="group1-name1" />
<input name="group1-name2" />

<input name="group2-name3" />
<input name="group2-name4" />
<input name="group2-name5" />

<select name="field-choice">
    <option value="group1">Group 1</option>
    <option value="group2">Group 2</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('select[name=field-choice]').change(function(){
        var groupName = $(this).val();
        $('input').hide().filter('[name^=' + groupName + ']').show();
    });

    // We need to hide all fields except those of the first group:
    $('input').hide().filter('[name^=group1]').show();
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

To fire up the code on load, just add .change(). As shown below...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.viewMap = {
    '0' : $([]),
    'view1' : $('#view1'),
    'view2' : $('#view2a, #view2b'),
    'view3' : $('#view3')
  };

  $('#viewSelector').change(function() {
    // hide all
    $.each($.viewMap, function() { this.hide(); });
    // show current
    $.viewMap[$(this).val()].show();
  }).change();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents :
I needed to show/hide fields depending on many previous select value (not only one).

So I add a parent attribute to div fields like this :

```
<div id="view" parent="none">
<select class=selector id="view">
<option value="0"> -- Make a choice --</option>
<option value="s1">sub 1</option>
<option value="s2">sub 2</option>
<option value="s3">sub 3</option>
</select>
</div>

<!-- you need to define the parent value with the value of parent div id -->
<div id="s1" parent="view">
<!-- if you want to have a selector be sure it has the same id as the div -->
<select class=selector id="s1">
<option value="0">-- Make a choice --</option>
<option value="s1_sub1">sub 1 of s1</option>
<option value="s1_sub2">sub 2 of s1</option>
<option value="s1_sub3">sub 3 of s1</option>
</select>
</div>

<!-- Make the same thing for s2 and s3
Define div s2 here

Define div s3 here
-->

<!-- and finally if that's your final step you put what you want in the div -->
<div id="s1_sub1" parent="s1">
You are inside s1 sub1
</div>
```

Now the jquery code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('select[class=selector]').change(function() { 
    //next div to show
    var selectorActive = $(this).val();
    //div where you are 
    var parentValue = $(this).attr("id");

   //show active div and hide others
    $('div').hide().filter('#' + selectorActive).show();

    while (parentValue!="none") {
      //then show parents of active div
      $('div[id=' + parentValue + ']').show();
      //return the parent of div until "none"
      parentValue = $('div[id=' + parentValue + ']').attr("parent");
     }

 });

// print only the first div at start
 $('div').hide().filter("#view").show();

});
```

That's works like a charm and you don't need to define maps

I hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

@Martin Try this

```
`$('#viewSelector').trigger('change');`
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Here is a very simple example:

The purpose is to show A SIMPLE EXAMPLE of how to use an array of values to show/hide fields depending upon the value of a select.

In this demo, I *could have* used the classNames to show/hide the group of fields all-at-once -- but that's not the purpose of the example -- so the classNames were used only for CSS.

Because the demo uses IDs *(with two arrays of these IDs)* for the demo, it doesn't matter whether the fields to be hidden are `input` fields, `divs`, `imgs` or what-have-you. The ID identifies whatever-it-is-to-be-hid.

```js
var aPeople = ['bob','sam','ted'];
var aTransport = ['car','bike','truck'];

$('#mySel').change(function(){
   $('.alldiv').hide(); //Hide them all to start...
   let sel = $(this).val(); //Get selected option value
   if ( sel=='ppl' ){
      for (let i=0; i<aPeople.length;i++){
         $('#' + aPeople[i]).show();
      }
   }else if ( sel=='tpt' ){
      for (let i=0; i<aTransport.length;i++){
         $('#' + aTransport[i]).show();
      }
   }else{
      //Choose selected
      $('.alldiv').show();
   }
});
```

```css
.alldiv{width:30vw;height:10vh;padding:2vh 2vw;text-align:center;}
.ppl{background:palegreen;}
.tpt{background:wheat;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="mySel">
  <option value="">Choose:</option>
  <option value="ppl">People</option>
  <option value="tpt">Vehicles</option>
</select>

<div id="bob" class="alldiv ppl">People: Bob</div>
<div id="car" class="alldiv tpt">Vehicle: Car</div>
<div id="truck" class="alldiv tpt">Vehicle: Truck</div>
<div id="sam" class="alldiv ppl">People: Sam</div>
<div id="ted" class="alldiv ppl">People: Ted</div>
<div id="bike" class="alldiv tpt">Vehicle: Bike</div>
```