# How to toggle visibility when user makes a selection

Tags: javascript, html, select, toggle, visibility

I have a select form with several options. I also have a div that I would like to show ONLY when a particular option is selected. Could you guys point me in the right direction? What would be the easiest thing to use for this?

Thank you :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/835259/show-hide-fields-depening-on-select-value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple and non-jQuery solution

```
window.onload=function() {
  var sel = document.getElementById("sel1");
  sel.onchange=function() {
     document.getElementById("otherDiv").style.display=(this.value=="other")?"":"none";
  }
  sel.onchange(); // set the visibility onload too in case of reload
}

<select id="sel1">
.
.
.
<option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
<div id="otherDiv">Other options</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I actually ended up using this one. jQuery can be a bit complicated sometimes!

Comment: I am getting to like jQuery more and more, but it should not be a knee-jerk solution to everything - especially not a simple page that is not already using jQuery. Here at SO you will likely get a suggestion to use jQuery within a few seconds of asking how to add a and b ;)

Answer (score 2):

[jQuery](http://jquery.com) is a powerful javascript library that makes this kind of task trivial. Here is an example of what you're trying to do using it: [jQuery - Using the radio button to show/hide a div.](http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=253174.0)