# How to make forms appear and disappear using php/java/jQuery/etc?

Tags: java, php, html, forms

I need to know how can I make a page that acts like this one:

http://www.stampile.ro/comanda.php

How can I make the forms appear and disappear?

Can you show me how? I have all the forms and the radio button but I don't know how to create something like that.

Comment: this question can not be answered, just go through basic html tutorials first. This is not an academy but question answer site

Comment: What forms? I couldn't find any appearing and disappearing forms on that page.

Comment: Everything on that page, except the images, is form-based...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the content of a `<div>` using jquery. Basicly it works like this:

```
$('.click').click(function() {

var content = "<img src='test.jpg'> <p>lorum ipsum ipsum ipsum </p>"
// replace the contents of the div with the new contents
$('#content-container').html(lcontent);

// cancel the default action of the link by returning false
return false;
});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/n9Vb9/

When using this in a form I want to advice you to take a look at this page: [Show/hide fields depending on select value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835259/show-hide-fields-depending-on-select-value)

Comment: I tried to do something like this: $('#comanda').click(function(){
    $('$theForm').hide('fast');
 $('$theForm1').hide('fast');
    $('$theForm2').show('fast');
}); where comanda is the name of the button and theForm1,2 and so on are the names of the Forms !