# Do action when item selected

Tags: php, html, select, drop-down-menu, menu

I need to make some actions depending on which item from my dropdown box is selected.

So I need to make it if an item with prefix Blue is selected then show one textbox below, and if any other item is selected then show some other stuff, how could I do that the easiest way?

More explaination:
Ok...I have a dropdown menu which contains a list of items. What I need to make is so that after they select an item with prefix Blue a input field under dropdown menu shows. If they select any other item something else will happen.

What I have so far is my dropdown menu:

```
<select id="select1" name="selectz1">
<?php
$id = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "<option value=$id>$row[0]</option>";
    $id++;
}
?>
</select>
```

And that is what HTML generates:

```
<form action="ThisPage.php" method="POST">
Accounts: <br />
<select id="select1" name="selectz1">
<option value=0>account 2000-01</option><option value=1>account 2000-02</option>
<option value=2>blue 2000-03</option><option value=3>blue 2000-04</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: Depended..What have you tried so far?

Comment: Well so far I have made my dropdown menu where users can select an item... dont really know how could I go about that to show something if 1 item is selected or something else if other is selected..

Comment: I really hope more then you did..

Comment: I ... I'm impressed with you, @user1914940.  Normally such burns are left to the professionals, but that was pretty darn good.  Unfortunately your question is so vague as to be unanswerable.  Could you perhaps edit in some of the code you've written to tackle your problem, and describe what you've tried to get it working?

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand what you mean by your first 2 sentences, please explain :) Also I have added more info and code in my first post as you requested.

Comment: @user1914940, I'll explain later.  Could you now edit in some of the *generated HTML*?  With real data please.

Comment: Sorry, could you please tell me what you mean with generated HTML and real data?

Comment: Sure.  I mean, visit your working script in a browser, with the actual dropdown menu, view source, and copy/paste the generated `<select>` and all of the `<option>`s.  Don't anonymize or tamper with the data, it could throw off the answers.  Most of them already have the general *gist* of things, by the way: use Javascript to take an action when the select menu is touched.

Comment: Ok, thanks :) I've added what HTML generates in my first post..

Comment: Great!  Make note in future questions that we really like having the troublesome code.  Without it, we have to make a *lot* of guesses.  The fewer the details, the more likely that you'll get the question closed instead of answered.  Lemme type something up.

Comment: So, I'm unable to close this as a duplicate, but this is a duplicate.  Please see: [**Show/hide fields depending on select value**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/835259/168868).  The answers there aren't much better than the ones here, but Stack Overflow *hates* duplicate questions.  You can find other similar questions by [using the site's search tool](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=How+do+I+show+and+hide+form+fields+based+on+the+value+of+a+select%3F) -- that link will take you to a search query with a bunch of questions that *should* help you.

Comment: Well I tried that example with jquery, but my values are not added manually but with while loop..

Comment: There, it took half an hour, but I did it.  Enjoy.  I'm gonna head to bed now, hopefully this'll still be here in the morning.  :p

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try to add this to my site now and will come back :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So, the question, as I understand it is: "How do I show and hide form fields based on the value of a `<select>`?"

Before we get started, this is a [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/835259/168868).  I'm *deeply* unsatisfied with the quality of answers there, so I'm going to fly in the face of convention and post my own.

First things first, all of the other answers here are totally on the right track, but they currently fail to explain *why* they do what they do.

Like others, I'm going to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) in this example.  jQuery is an awesome Javascript library that greatly eases a bunch of repetitive, verbose tasks.  jQuery exposes an function called `$` -- yes, just a dollar sign -- that lets you access and modify the page.

#### Step 1

Let's create a minimal example, similar to your existing code.

```
<form>
    <select name="select1" id="select1">
        <option value="1">account 001</option>
        <option value="2">account 002</option>
        <option value="3">blue 001</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1">
</form>
```

Important things to point out:

1. Modern HTML requires that attribute values (`value="1"`) be quoted.
2. All the elements we need to target with jQuery need to be easily identifiable.  We're using `id`s here.

#### Step 2

Let's attach an [event listener](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/).  Events are things that happen while you interact with the page.  In our case, we're going to listen to the `<select>` for the `change` event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#select1').on('change', function(event) {
        alert(this.value);
    });
});
</script>
```

That's a whole lot of jargon in not much space.  Let me explain a bit.

- `$()` is a function call to jQuery.
- `$(function(){ ... })` is passing a *function* to the jQuery object.  This is a *shortcut* that says "jQuery, when the page is done loading, run this function."
- `$('#select1')` asks jQuery to find the element `id`'d with "select1"
- `$('#select1').on('change', function ...)` asks jQuery to watch for the `change` event, and execute the requested function.
- Finally, inside the function itself, we're going to throw an `alert` dialog with the current value of the `select` element.

Here's a [demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZBL4c/).

#### Step 3

Now we have some Javascript running whenever the select menu is changed.  Let's show and hide that text box!

First, we need to make it hidden.  Because we're showing and hiding it with Javascript, we should tell it to only hide when Javascript can run.  Hiding things from people that can't run Javascript makes them grumpy.  So, we'll add a new line to our onload handler:

```
$(function() {
    $('#text1').hide();
    $('#select1'). // ...
});
```

If you guessed that new line is "ask jQuery to hide the text1 element," you guessed correctly!

Now, how do we watch for "blue" options?  Head back up to that jsfiddle and play with it.  Did you notice that the `value` of the `option` is being alerted?  Those aren't blue at all!  We need to actually get to the *selected `option`* instead of just the value.  That's a bit funnier.

Let's take a peek at [MDN's documentation on `<select>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/select).  It tells us that it's going to expose itself as a [HTMLSelectElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLSelectElement).  Not a big surprise.  It has a property called `selectedIndex`, which tells us which `option` has been picked, and it has a property called `options`, which gives us direct access to the options themselves.  Sweet!

Let's update the onload again:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#text1').hide();
    $('#select1').on('change', function(event) {
        var opt = this.options[ this.selectedIndex ];
        alert('You picked ' + $(opt).text());
    });
});
</script>
```

Again, a [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cQGmc/2/).

`options` there is an array. Javascript, like PHP, uses square brackets to access array elements.

So, we're picking our option, then wrapping it in jQuery then calling the [`text` method](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to get the *text node* inside the element, as opposed to the form value.

Great, now we have a *string*.  What can we do with it?

#### Step 4

Like PHP, Javascript has [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), a way to do pattern matching.  Hey, we have a pattern to match against!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#text1').hide();
    $('#select1').on('change', function(event) {
        var opt = this.options[ this.selectedIndex ];
        var picked_blue = $(opt).text().match(/blue/i);
        if(picked_blue) {
            alert('You picked a blue option!');
        } else {
            alert('You did not pick a blue option.');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Again, a [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ku6sA/1/).

We're now using the [`match` method on the `String` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to use a regex.  In particular, a regex that looks for the characters `blue`, in a case-insensitive manner (the `i` at the end does that).

This code should be detecting blue things now.  Time to finally hide and show that text field!

#### Step 5

Let's dive right in.

```
$(function() {
    $('#text1').hide();
    $('#select1').on('change', function(event) {
        var opt = this.options[ this.selectedIndex ];
        var picked_blue = $(opt).text().match(/blue/i);
        if(picked_blue) {
            $('#text1').show();
        } else {
            $('#text1').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

​

Did you see it coming?  Can you guess what it does?

Here's the [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Z6K4b/1/).

And here we are, mission accomplished.  You can apply this same technique to all sorts of stuff.

Pay attention to the links I've scattered throughout here, especially to jsfiddle, which is a **great** playground for Javascript and HTML, and to the MDN sites, which are a *great* Javascript and HTML reference.  Oh, and to the jQuery manual.

Comment: You sir...are awesome :) Just 1 more thing...how can I display something else if they selected an option without prefix blue?

Comment: Sure, it's just a matter of adding more branches in the `if` block, by adding `elseif`s.

Comment: Great, thanks for explaining :) Could you open a chat for 5minutes please?

Comment: Come join us over in the [PHP room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php), though I won't be on for long.

Comment: i would like to say even after a year, is that, you're one heck of an awesome people that actually took time to explain all this to us! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using Javascript.

Give id to your dropdown box. When it is selected toggle divs according to its value. Value can be get by, `var item= document.getElementById('id').value;` . then,

```
function toggle()
{

var item= document.getElementById('yourdropdownid').value;

    if(item=='yourfirstoption')
    {
    document.getElementById('div1id').style.display="block";
    document.getElementById('div2id').style.display="none";
    }
    else if(item=='yoursecondoption')
    {
    document.getElementById('div2id').style.display="block";
    document.getElementById('div1id').style.display="none";
    }
}
```

An example is [here](http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/02/12/how-to-hide-and-show-your-div/). Its not an exact example. But I hope you can find your solution from it by connecting with this post. Good luck.

Comment: Well if I understand that correct, the div will not show as soon as they select an option from dropdown, but they have to submit it, right? I need to make it so that as soon as they select an option an element shows up.

Comment: If you are using dropdown box You dont want to submit it. The divs will toggle as well as you selects different options.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("change", "#color", function(){
        value = $(this).val().split('-')[0]; // extracting the color prefix from selected value
        if(value == 'Blue') // checking if value is Blue
        {
            $('#other').hide(); // hiding the div having id "other"
            $('#blue').show(); //showing div having id"blue"
        }

        else // if selected value have prefix other than Blue 
        {
            $('#blue').hide(); //hide the div having id "blue"
            $('#other').show(); // show the div having id "other"
        }

    });
</script>
<style>
    /* hiding both divs by default, these div will show up on dropdown change event depending upon the selected value */
    #blue, #other{display: none;}
</style>

<select id="color" name="color">
    <option value="">--Select--</option>
    <option value="Blue-value">Blue</option>
    <option value="Red-value">Red</option>
    <option value="Black-value">Black</option>
</select>

<div id="blue">
    your blue div
</div>

<div id="other">
    your other div
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, I've tried that, but nothing happens when I select an item from a dropdown menu. Ive put both scripts in head, style, select and divs in my body..

Comment: -1; while this will work, you have failed to explain anything about what the code is, does, how it works, what it uses, etc.

Comment: @Charles thanks for your feedback, the script was already doing its job but now I explained all things by adding comments. I expect +1 now.

Comment: @user1914940 the script is 100% bug free, what error you getting?

Comment: @TahirYasin While I have now retracted my downvote, please be aware that inline comments can be a real bear to read, and you should explain what you're doing entirely outside of the code for obviousness and clarity.