# jQuery doesn't seem to be working on browsers

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to hide/display fields according to which selection is made in a drop down menu.

[Reference Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835259/show-hide-fields-depending-on-select-value)

The code for the jQuery doesn't seem to be taking. Any suggestions? New to jQuery. I'm saving my files as .php

jQuery:

```
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $.viewMap = {
                    '0' : $([]),
                    'view1' : $('#view1'),
                    'view2' : $('#view2a, #view2b'),
                    'view3' : $('#view3')
                };
                $('#viewSelector').change(function() {
                    // hide all
                    $.each($.viewMap, function() { this.hide(); });
                    // show current
                    $.viewMap[$(this).val()].show();
                });
            });
        </script>
</head>
```

html:

```
<select id="viewSelector">
       <option value="0">-- Select a View --</option>       
       <option value="view1">view1</option>
       <option value="view2">view2</option>
       <option value="view3">view3</option>
</select>

    <select id="viewSelector">
       <option value="0">-- Select a View --</option>       
       <option value="view1">view1</option>
       <option value="view2">view2</option>
       <option value="view3">view3</option>
    </select>

    <div id="view1">
      <!-- content --> 
    </div>
    <div id="view2a">
      <!-- content --> 
    </div>
    <div id="view2b">
      <!-- content --> 
    </div>
    <div id="view3">
    <!-- content --> 
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you opened the broswer's console and corrected any errors showing there?

Comment: You have duplicated your select including its ID. Please note only the first will work with jQuery if you have duplicate IDs (or is that a cut/paste mistake?)

Comment: _this.hide();_ doesn't seem to be correct.

Comment: It is quite daring to title *jQuery doesn't seem to be working on browsers*... you should maybe consider the possibility that you made a mistake...

Comment: @trincot apologies poor wording on my part and I rushed my question, it was obviously my mistake, thought I was executing the jQuery wrong and my browser wasn't taking it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a duplicate `<select>`. If you remove it, the view selector works:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3uhh0ur2/)

If there are any jQuery issues occurring behind the scenes due to code outside of what you posted, press F12 in Chrome to open the [DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/?hl=en), and click the [Console tab](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/console/console-ui?hl=en) to see any JavaScript errors after refreshing the page.

Comment: How would I hide the fields initially displaying when the page loads? I only want to display them when the select is used not prior.

Comment: Set the style on the divs to "display:none" using CSS. When .show() is then called in your .load(), that property becomes "display: block". You could also accomplish the same thing using .hide() in your .ready() method, but if the document was slow to load, the divs would show until the document was finished loading, then would suddenly hide themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Ids should be unique. In your code, there are 2 selects with same id `viewSelector`. You may remove one set.

Give each div a common class like;

```
<div class="views" id="view3">
```

Then try to hide all divs using this class. Then show the required div on drop down select. The entire code may look like;

```
$.viewMap = {
  '0': $([]),
  'view1': $('#view1'),
  'view2': $('#view2a, #view2b'),
  'view3': $('#view3')
};
$('#viewSelector').change(function() {
  // hide all
  $(".views").hide();
  // show current
  $.viewMap[$(this).val()].show();
});
```

**[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/pthg3kw9/)** is a demo. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#viewSelector').change(function() {
       $('.view').hide();
      // show current
       if($(this).val() !== 0){
         if($(this).val() == "view2"){
             $("#view2a, #view2b").show();
         }else{
             $("#"+ $(this).val()).show();
         }
       }
   });
});
```

HTML:

```
<select id="viewSelector">
   <option value="0">-- Select a View --</option>       
   <option value="view1">view1</option>
   <option value="view2">view2</option>
   <option value="view3">view3</option>
</select>

<div id="view1" class="view">
  <!-- content --> 
</div>
<div id="view2a" class="view">
  <!-- content --> 
</div>
<div id="view2b" class="view">
  <!-- content --> 
</div>
<div id="view3" class="view">
<!-- content --> 
</div>
```